# Error on the MSDN page for base constructors (c#)

Tags: c#, constructor, radix

I think there is an error in the following page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx about constructors and invoking base constructors right after the following paragraph:

> "The use of the this keyword in the previous example causes this constructor to be called:"

```
public Employee(int annualSalary)
{
salary = annualSalary;
}
```

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
{
salary = weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks;
}
```

Can anyone confirm? thanks a lot

Comment: No - because it's passing weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks that will find a constructor accepting a single int

Comment: That is another way to do it but the documentation if correct.  And the preferred way in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's showing you the source of the constructor is being called by `this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)`... and that's the *single-parameter* constructor which just assigns to the `salary` variable.

Think of the code as being like this:

```
// Constructor X
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    : this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}

// Constructor Y
public Employee(int annualSalary)
{
    salary = annualSalary;
}
```

And then the documentation as:

> The expression `this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)` in constructor X indicates a chained call to constructor Y.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering

Answer (score 0):

No the documentation is accurate.  Think of the 2 argument constructor acting like a method overload calling the main implementation of the method.

The 2 argument constructor

```
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
    : this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}
```

is truly calling the previously defined 1 argument constructor where the `annualSalary` argument is the calculated value of `weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks` .

```
public Employee(int annualSalary)
{
    salary = annualSalary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that explains a lot